# Calling functions as dynamic function as array values in javascript

Tags: javascript

Okay so in PHP we can call function as dynamic variables something like

```
$obj = new $class;
$obj->$myFoo($args);
```

But I am trying the same thing in Javascript but it's not working. The error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: foo is not a function
```

My javascript code looks like this

```
function getId(arr){
    for(let i in arr){
        console.log("Function getId "+ arr[i]);
    }
}
function getMarker(arr){
    for(let i in arr){
        console.log("Function getMarker "+ arr[i]);
    }
}
const PAGEAPP = {
    processes:["getId","getMarker"],
    init:() => {
        for(let foo of PAGEAPP.processes){
            foo([1,2,3]);
        }
    },
}
```

Is there anyway I can access the same in Javascript.

Thank you in advance for your TIME :)

**EDIT**

This is what chrome showing

[image]

Comment: That is because your function names are strings inside the array instead of variables

Comment: Glad, I was able to help:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use function names rather than using strings

```js
function getId(arr) {
  for (let i in arr) {
    console.log("Function getId " + arr[i]);
  }
}

function getMarker(arr) {
  for (let i in arr) {
    console.log("Function getMarker " + arr[i]);
  }
}
const PAGEAPP = {
  processes: [getId, getMarker],
  init: () => {
    for (let foo of PAGEAPP.processes) {
      foo([1, 2, 3]);

    }
  },
}

PAGEAPP.init()
```

Comment: I know how to call it but My concern is after calling it, it's not working as supposed

Comment: It is doing what you are telling it to do. Run the code snippet. Also can you show us the expected output of your code?